# Whats wrong with my site's code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I may be a bit burned out, but is there something wrong with where I put the code on my site?

Live on my site, not working at all
http://japaneselanguagefriend.com/apptest.html

Here it is on JSfiddle working just fine.
 http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/PT523/3/

Thanks to Adeneo for helping with this code!

Comment: Define "working just fine", we need to know what is supposed to do

Comment: When a user types in na, ma, and ba, the pictures will change, try it here http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/PT523/3/   It is a very rough draft for a project I am working on, but you get the idea.  Any ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not including jQuery in your test page. The console says

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

And you aren't including jquery.js either from a CDN or locally in your code.

Include

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
```

in your page, or host your own copy locally. Using a CDN is recommended as a cached copy may already be available on the client, which speeds up page load times.

**Always** have your browser's error console open when testing and debugging JavaScript. You will catch and fix most if not all syntactical or technical errors with it open.

Comment: your profile msg is ambiguous, I suggest 'reached 10k', otherwise it seems that you earned 10k in one day

Comment: @ajax333221 Good point, although I don't explicitly state I earned it in one day. You can interpret it however you like ;)